# Reactive and Non Reactive repository in a Spring Boot application with H2 database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-data-r2dbc

In addition to a non-reactive JPA repository, I introduced a reactive repository in my Spring Boot app with H2 database.

```
com.app.respository.BusinessRepository extends JpaRepository
com.app.respository.r2dbc.PendingBusinessRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository
```

And I added a connection factory for reactive H2.

```
@Configuration
@EnableR2dbcRepositories
public class R2DBCConfiguration extends AbstractR2dbcConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public H2ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        return new H2ConnectionFactory(
                H2ConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                        .url("jdbc:h2:file:~/data/demo-rxdb")
                        .username("sa")
                        .password("password")
                        .build());
    }
}
```

After this change, my application is not able to find the non-reactive repository. It says:

> Field businessRepository in
> com.app.service.BusinessServiceImpl required a bean
> of type 'com.app.repository.BusinessRepository' that could not be
> found.
>
> The injection point has the following annotations:
>
> - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
> 'com.app.repository.BusinessRepository' in your configuration.

I can only guess that maybe my H2 database is now reactive (non-blocking) which is not supported by a JPARepository (blocking). But is my assumption correct?

I have mixed needs. I need only `PendingBusiness` table data in a non-blocking way (which is constantly being fluxed out on UI through event stream) and I need the rest of the tables' data in a traditional blocking way. Is it possible to achieve what I want through a single H2 database instance?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to use both Spring Data R2DBC and Spring Data JPA in a single Spring boot application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62253297/is-it-possible-to-use-both-spring-data-r2dbc-and-spring-data-jpa-in-a-single-spr)

Comment: Hi Hantsy, In your example, do both repositories work on a single instance of a database? Or would there be two instances, one for each repository? I have two repositories and used your JpaConfig and R2DBCconfig but when my application starts I do not see reactive repository failed to inject in the service. I am using H2 file-based database.